# Querying Exchange 2003 for Information About Attachments

Tags: exchange, query, attachment

I'm looking into the possibility of switching from Microsoft Office to Google Apps. Although Google Apps are not currently as feature rich as the Microsoft Product, the Google tools provide greater colloboration support (online sharing and editing, close integration with chat, video calls, etc).

I suspect in my workplace that the majority of Documents, Spreadsheets and Presentations produced are used for internal colloboration so the benefits of improved colloboration would outweigh the 'pixel perfect' features that Office has.

To prove this point, I'd like to be able to query our Exchange 2003 system for the following metrics

- How many attachments of various types are sent to internal recipients
- How many attachements of various types are sent to external recipients

The attachment types are primarily .doc, .xls and .ppt but it would be nice to be able to generalize the query.

I've tried using the stats from the archiving system but this only shows the number of messages with attachements - not they're types - I suspect a lot of users have an image as part of a header/footer so that information is not very useful.

Any pointers to relevant articles on querying the meta information in the Exchange Database or tools that are available to get this information would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of Exchange reporting tools that can walk the mailbox databases and give you reports with the answers you're looking for. Take a look at http://www.msexchange.org/software/Reporting/ for one list of products and see whether any of them have a trial or free version that might meet your needs.